# Devise Error No route matches [POST] "/users/sign_up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am currently trying out devise to set up a login and password on my site. I am currently running it locally. When I try to sign up for my site, this is the error message that I get "No route matches [POST] "/users/sign_up"

```
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
                    root GET    /                              pages#home
                   about GET    /about(.:format)               pages#about
```

these are my routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  root "pages#home"
  get "about" => "pages#about"
end
```

Comment: please let us know the code in your view

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are using [button_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) on your view, which implements a form with a POST method by default.

```
<%= button_to "New", action: "new" %>
# => "<form method="post" action="/controller/new" class="button_to">
#      <input value="New" type="submit" />
#    </form>"
```

Try [link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Actually in the routes for /users/sign_up the method type is "Get" and I think you used method type as "Post", so it differs.

Your request is post request and but it should be get request.

You can change the method type from "Post" to "Get". you need to make this change on your form 
where you specify the method type.